# Heavy IO causes NVMe controller is down; will reset

Tags: linux-mint, ssd, crash, nvme

My laptop has a [Kingston KC3000](https://www.kingston.com/unitedkingdom/en/ssd/kc3000-nvme-m2-solid-state-drive) NVMe SSD which becomes unavilable during heavy IO. This is my boot drive so this issue causes Linux to crash. I have tried setting the kernel parameters `nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0` and `pcie_aspm=off` however this has not resolved the issue. I don't believe the cause is thermal throttling because the drive temperature was 61°C when it errored and the operating temperature is specified as 0°C~70°C. I don't know whether this is a hardware issue or software bug and I am not sure what to attempt next.

### Reproduction

I can reproduce the issue with a large write using [fio](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html)

```
mint@mint:~$ fio --name=write_test_100GB --rw=write --size=100GB --filename=/mnt/303637a5-5c86-467e-938e-af26d8d667e0/fio
write_test_100GB: (g=0): rw=write, bs=(R) 4096B-4096B, (W) 4096B-4096B, (T) 4096B-4096B, ioengine=psync, iodepth=1
fio-3.28
Starting 1 process
write_test_100GB: Laying out IO file (1 file / 102400MiB)
fio: io_u error on file /mnt/303637a5-5c86-467e-938e-af26d8d667e0/fio: Read-only file system: write offset=76983128064, buflen=4096
fio: pid=4636, err=30/file:io_u.c:1845, func=io_u error, error=Read-only file system

write_test_100GB: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err=30 (file:io_u.c:1845, func=io_u error, error=Read-only file system): pid=4636: Sun Apr  9 10:14:44 2023
  write: IOPS=190k, BW=743MiB/s (779MB/s)(71.7GiB/98845msec); 0 zone resets
    clat (nsec): min=1306, max=29625M, avg=4996.06, stdev=6834410.60
     lat (nsec): min=1329, max=29625M, avg=5030.62, stdev=6834410.60
    clat percentiles (nsec):
     |  1.00th=[ 1464],  5.00th=[ 1496], 10.00th=[ 1512], 20.00th=[ 1592],
     | 30.00th=[ 1784], 40.00th=[ 1976], 50.00th=[ 2256], 60.00th=[ 2480],
     | 70.00th=[ 2928], 80.00th=[ 3440], 90.00th=[ 4512], 95.00th=[ 5792],
     | 99.00th=[ 8896], 99.50th=[10688], 99.90th=[19072], 99.95th=[26240],
     | 99.99th=[47872]
   bw (  MiB/s): min=    5, max= 2064, per=100.00%, avg=1056.23, stdev=318.45, samples=139
   iops        : min= 1500, max=528396, avg=270394.14, stdev=81524.32, samples=139
  lat (usec)   : 2=40.73%, 4=45.10%, 10=13.51%, 20=0.56%, 50=0.09%
  lat (usec)   : 100=0.01%, 250=0.01%, 500=0.01%, 750=0.01%, 1000=0.01%
  lat (msec)   : 2=0.01%, 4=0.01%, 10=0.01%, 20=0.01%, 50=0.01%
  lat (msec)   : 100=0.01%, 250=0.01%, >=2000=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=6.94%, sys=50.32%, ctx=2332, majf=0, minf=26
  IO depths    : 1=100.0%, 2=0.0%, 4=0.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.1%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=0,18794710,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=1

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=743MiB/s (779MB/s), 743MiB/s-743MiB/s (779MB/s-779MB/s), io=71.7GiB (77.0GB), run=98845-98845msec
```

This causes the controller reset followed by the driver becoming unavailable

```
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.267878] nvme nvme0: controller is down; will reset: CSTS=0xffffffff, PCI_STATUS=0x10
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.339860] nvme 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.340571] nvme nvme0: Removing after probe failure status: -19
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.363768] nvme0n1: detected capacity change from 4000797360 to 0
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.363827] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 25368832 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x1000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.363826] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 3792103000 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 6 prio class 0
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.363842] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 3792105560 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 6 prio class 0
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.363841] BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p2): bdev /dev/nvme0n1p2 errs: wr 0, rd 1, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.363864] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 3792108120 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 6 prio class 0
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.363871] BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p2): bdev /dev/nvme0n1p2 errs: wr 1, rd 1, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.363968] BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p2): bdev /dev/nvme0n1p2 errs: wr 1, rd 2, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.364180] BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p2): bdev /dev/nvme0n1p2 errs: wr 1, rd 3, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.364311] BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p2): bdev /dev/nvme0n1p2 errs: wr 1, rd 4, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.364834] BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p2): bdev /dev/nvme0n1p2 errs: wr 1, rd 5, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.364898] BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p2): bdev /dev/nvme0n1p2 errs: wr 1, rd 6, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.365008] BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p2): bdev /dev/nvme0n1p2 errs: wr 1, rd 7, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.365084] BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p2): bdev /dev/nvme0n1p2 errs: wr 1, rd 8, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.365111] BTRFS: error (device nvme0n1p2) in btrfs_run_delayed_refs:2149: errno=-5 IO failure
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.365117] BTRFS info (device nvme0n1p2): forced readonly
Apr  9 10:14:44 mint kernel: [  816.366446] BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p2): bdev /dev/nvme0n1p2 errs: wr 2, rd 8, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
```

I tried the same write test against the other NVMe SSD in the computer - a TEAM MP33 PRO - which did not crash. However the cache filled and the drive performance crawled to a halt.

### Research

The Arch Wiki has a section on [Controller failure due to broken APST support](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Solid_state_drive/NVMe#Power_Saving_(APST) which mentions earlier Kingston drives and older kernels. There are no firmware updates for my drive and I'm running the 5.19 Kernel.

I have also read these which suggest the `default_ps_max_latency_us` and `pcie_aspm` tweaks.

- [ServerFault - Linus/ext4/nvme crashes during high io](https://serverfault.com/questions/1011077/linus-ext4-nvme-crashes-during-high-io)
- [Ask Ubuntu - Ask Ubuntu - Random Freezes in Kubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266413/random-freezes-in-kubuntu-20-04)
- [Ask Ubuntu - WD (Sandisk) NVMe M.2 stick not quite working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126456/wd-sandisk-nvme-m-2-stick-not-quite-working)
- [Linux Mailing List - [BUG][5.18rc5] nvme nvme0: controller is down; will reset: CSTS=0xffffffff, PCI_STATUS=0x10](https://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/2205.0/04950.html)
- [r/pop_os - Experiencing random freezes after installing new NVME SSD](https://old.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/g8y3ae/experiencing_random_freezes_after_installing_new/)
- [Arch Linux Forum - NVMe SSD I/O errors, not sure if hardware failure](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=254161)

### System Information

#### inxi

```
System:
  Host: minted Kernel: 5.19.0-38-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: Cinnamon 5.6.8 Distro: Linux Mint 21.1 Vera
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Metabox product: Flo L140PU v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: IT Channel Pty model: L140PU serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: INSYDE v: 1.07.03TMB date: 05/17/2022
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 49.0 Wh (67.8%) condition: 72.3/73.9 Wh (97.8%)
    volts: 8.0 min: 7.7
CPU:
  Info: 10-core (2-mt/8-st) model: 12th Gen Intel Core i5-1235U bits: 64
    type: MST AMCP cache: L2: 6.5 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2343 min/max: 400/4400:3300 cores: 1: 575 2: 2500
    3: 684 4: 2500 5: 2500 6: 2806 7: 2500 8: 3281 9: 2500 10: 3281 11: 2500
    12: 2500
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: Chicony USB2.0 Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 resolution: 1: 2560x1440~60Hz
    2: 2560x1440~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.5
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio
    driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: Audioengine D1 24-bit DAC type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid
  Device-3: Antlion Audio USB Microphone type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-38-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.66 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi
  IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: 70:a6:cc:2e:c9:35
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX201 Bluetooth type: USB driver: btusb
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: down
    bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block: hardware: no software: yes
    address: 70:A6:CC:2E:C9:39
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 2.33 TiB used: 2.02 TiB (86.8%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Kingston model: SKC3000D2048G size: 1.86 TiB
  ID-2: /dev/nvme1n1 vendor: TeamGroup model: TM8FPD512G size: 476.94 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 1.86 TiB used: 1.68 TiB (89.9%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 486 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
  ID-3: /home size: 1.86 TiB used: 1.68 TiB (89.9%) fs: btrfs
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 1.91 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%)
    dev: /dev/nvme1n1p1
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 66.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 354 Uptime: 4m Memory: 23.19 GiB used: 2.17 GiB (9.3%)
  Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.13
```

#### lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4601 (rev 04)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 46a8 (rev 0c)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Participant (rev 04)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0 (rev 04)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 04)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator (rev 04)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Platform Monitoring Technology (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 04)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 01)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51bd (rev 01)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51b0 (rev 01)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH eSPI Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. Device 5013 (rev 01)
2b:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
2c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation PS5013 E13 NVMe Controller (rev 01)
```

#### SMART

```
Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0 namespace-id:ffffffff
critical_warning                        : 0
temperature                             : 34 C (307 Kelvin)
available_spare                         : 100%
available_spare_threshold               : 10%
percentage_used                         : 0%
endurance group critical warning summary: 0
data_units_read                         : 17,450,136
data_units_written                      : 8,395,033
host_read_commands                      : 40,201,204
host_write_commands                     : 38,110,961
controller_busy_time                    : 268
power_cycles                            : 480
power_on_hours                          : 608
unsafe_shutdowns                        : 275
media_errors                            : 0
num_err_log_entries                     : 2,790
Warning Temperature Time                : 0
Critical Composite Temperature Time     : 0
Temperature Sensor 2                    : 77 C (350 Kelvin)
Thermal Management T1 Trans Count       : 7
Thermal Management T2 Trans Count       : 0
Thermal Management T1 Total Time        : 3830
Thermal Management T2 Total Time        : 0
```

#### APST

```
get-feature:0x0c (Autonomous Power State Transition), Current value:00000000
    Autonomous Power State Transition Enable (APSTE): Disabled
    Auto PST Entries    .................
```

Comment: Archlinux mentions a cli `nvme error-log <device>`. Does it  say anything useful?

Comment: @meuh, I'm not sure how to interpret the log. There's 4 entries that aren't `status_field: 0`, (all `0x2002(INVALID_FIELD…`), `error_count`s for those entries are 2816-2819. The `cmdid`s are `0x4002`, `0x4001`, `0x201b` and `0x10`. `parm_err_loc`s are `0x102c`,`0x102c`,`0x28` and `0xffff`.

I can't interrogate it after a drive failure because nvme0 gets removed after the probe failure.

Comment: `Temperature Sensor 2                    : 77 C` 

This IMO is not good. Please try installing a heatsink or improving cooling.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I think that's the controller temp. It didn't seem to change much so I wonder if it's a stuck sensor or a software bug. I've just replaced the drive with a WD SN850X which runs cooler and also hasn't exhibited the same crashing issue. I wonder if the Kingston's faulty or just doesn't play nice with Linux, I'll have to do some more investigation later.

Comment: I don't think Linux can be blamed for that. NVMe is an industry wide standard which has nothing special in terms of OS support. Some people had Power saving/ASPM issues under Linux in the past but that's because Linux allows far more aggressive power modes than most NVMe's support.